# What is the fastest way to calculate $(x+1)^3-(x-1)^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the fastest way to calculate $(x+1)^3-(x-1)^3$?

My teacher gives me this question, and I use 5 minutes to calculate it, and there is an error. I want to know if there is a faster method to do it.

Comment: use pascal triangle.

Comment: It kind of depends on how fast you are at calcs \begin{align}&(x+1)^3-(x-1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1-x^3+3x^2-3x+1=6x^2+2\\ &(x+1)^3-(x-1)^3=(x+1-x+1)((x+1)^2-(x+1)(x-1)+(x-1)^2)=\\ =&2(x^2+2x+1+x^2-1+x^2-2x+1)=2(3x^2+1)\end{align}

Comment: $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. More generally, $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$.

Comment: Since you made a mistake, there is a caution to take care: simplest is best - it is quick to use the binomial expansions and check the signs (and check a couple of values to make sure you haven' slipped up). In fact, if I were doing this for general exponent $n$ I would also use the binomial expansions, because I know those, and taking out the factor $2=(x+1)-(x-1)$ gives me an expression I have to work to simplify. You might observe straight off that this is an even function (with even exponent the function would be odd), and therefore you expect only even powers of $x$.

Comment: To be fair, what is faster depends on the person. For me personally, I would just expand using Pascal's triangle; however, other people may find that using the formula for the difference of two cubes to be quicker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$(1+x)^3+(1-x)^3$$ is an *even* polynomial of degree at most three. Hence the expansion has only even terms and must be of the form

$$ax^2+b.$$

Setting $x=0$, you find $b=2$, then with $x=1$, $a+b=8$ and you are done.

---

Alternatively, you may happen to know by heart the fourth row of Pascal's Triangle, $1\ 3\ 3\ 1$, and you get the coefficients $1+1,3-3,3+3,1-1$ (by increasing powers).

Comment: Again.....thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I like Pascal's triangle:   the third row gives the coefficients of $(x+a)^3$, namely,  $1331$.

So we get $(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$ and $(x-1)^3=x^3-3x^2+3x-1$.

Thus the difference is $6x^2+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$$

Comment: Having done both, I think this one is slower that actually cubing the polynomials. :P

Comment: I use this too it waste time to expand it

Comment: @MaxChan: If you observe that $a^2+ab+b^2=(a+b)^2-ab$, the calculation can go a little faster, since your $a$ and $b$ are conjugates.

Comment: @MaxChan You can use the fact that $(x+1)^2+(x-1)^2=2x^2+2$. More generally,$$(\alpha+\beta)^2+(\alpha-\beta)^2=2(\alpha^2+\beta^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{Method\ 1}:$ $$S=(x+1)^3 - (x-1)^3 = 2((x+1)^2 + (x-1)^2 + (x+1)(x-1))$$$$=2(2(x^2+1) + x^2 -1)$$ $$=2(3x^2 + 1)$$ $$=6x^2+2$$  $\mathbf{Method\ 2:}$ $$(x+1)^3 = \displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^3\binom 3rx^r$$ $$(x-1)^3=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^3(-1)^r\binom 3rx^r$$ Clearly in their addition only terms with even $r$ remain. Here, they are $r = 0,2$. So the sum is$$2\left(\binom 30 + \binom 32x^2\right)$$ $$=6x^2 + 2$$ In any case we have the solution $$\boxed{S = 6x^2+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it depends how fast you in calculation. It's same formula but different ways to write
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$
$$(x+1)^3=x^3+1+3x(x+1)$$
$$(x-1)^3=x^3-1-3x(x-1)$$
  $$... - .. +..+ $$
$$S=2+3x(x+1+x-1)=6x^2+2$$